# when pass static variable by value cause race condition in c

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, mutex, static-variables

do I need to add lock when pass (function scope) static variable by value:

Suppose I have a function - "myfunction" can be called by at least 2 thread:

```
int myfunction()
{  
    static int var;

    function2(var);
    return var;
}

void function2(int var)
{
    var++;
}
```

I am guessing that we need a lock to protect this, or passed by pointer, and lock inside the callee function. Because when convert to assembly code, it will be at least 2 operations:

```
move REG (var)

push REG
```

If the first thread calls move, and the second thread modified var. And when the first thread calls push, it will push the wrong value.

And things get worse when you pass 2-word value (64-bit), the high byte, and low byte value passed in will be mismatched/corrupted.

I think the solution is to pass by pointer and do mutex lock and unlock in "function2" or assign the static variable to a local variable, pass the local variable to function2, and before and after assignment do lock and unlock.

Am I correct?

Comment: `var` in `myfunction()` is not modified by `function2()`. See C11 draft standard `6.5.2.2 Function calls, Section 4 [...] In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93)A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments.`

Comment: `function2` modify a local copy of `myfunction` `var` value, and then get rid of it...

Comment: the static variable is uint64_t, funtcion2 is a simplified version, and there is also a function3. and function3 modifies this static variable. function2 should be like: if(var > constance){ some ops} else {other opts} so the "accuracy" of var passed in is  really important. And if after the first thread does push, the second thread execute function3, and modified static var, so the low byte and high byte will be mismatched (corrupted)

Comment: maybe I simplified my case too much. the static variable is uint64_t, funtcion2 is a simplified version, and there is also a function3. and function3 modifies this static variable. function2 should be like: if(var > constance){ some ops} else {other opts} so the "accuracy" of var passed in is really important. Suppose after the first thread pushes one byte, then the second thread execute function3, and modified static var, , then the first thread push the other byte. So the low byte and high byte pushed by the first thread will be mismatched (corrupted)

Answer (score 1):

Your current case doesn't matter since each thread to `function2` will get its own copy of `var` and the incremented value *not* reflected in the caller.

If you want to increment an integral type in a thread-safe manner, then use an appropriate type (`ATOMIC_VAR_INIT`?) and function (`atomic_fetch_add`?) from `<stdatomic.h>`. There's no point in writing your own function to do this.

Comment: maybe I simplified my case too much. the static variable is uint64_t, funtcion2 is a simplified version, and there is also a function3. and function3 modifies this static variable. function2 should be like: if(var > constance){ some ops} else {other opts} so the "accuracy" of var passed in is really important. Suppose after the first thread pushes one byte, then the second thread execute function3, and modified static var, , then the first thread push the other byte. So the low byte and high byte pushed by the first thread will be mismatched (corrupted)

Comment: In which case my recommendation of your using the C11 atomics library holds. Don't try to do this stuff yourself. Using mutual exclusion calls will be an order of magnitude slower.